# Gooddata Data loading in demo TwitterAPI project?

Tags: java, gooddata

```
Component [Twitter API call:TWITTER_API_CALL1] finished with status ERROR.
   Exception occurred during signing the request: GET org.apache.https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=gooddata&result_type=mixed&count=100 HTTP/1.1
    This consumer expects requests of type org.apache.http.HttpRequest

ERROR [main] - Execution of graph failed !
```

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22536931/edit) your question to include your Java code that makes the API call, as well as an explanation/question into your question? As it stands, this isn't a great question (since we don't have anything to go off of).

Comment: This is related to GoodData CloudConnect tool that makes the call. The Exception that is in the text is enough for debugging. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug on the CloudConnect side that will be fixed this Saturday 22nd March 2014. Just update the CloudConnect after this weekend and it should work. Anyway, if you try to Deploy this Data Loading process to the server, everything should be OK. The problem occurs just for the local run of CloudConnect.

JT